# Using an INNER JOIN to join two tables in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, inner-join, hibernate-mapping

I have an SQL query that I need to convert to an HQL query.

I have a class Item that contains a set of Components.  The SQL table for Item is DBO.W_ITEM and the table for Component is DBO.W_COMPONENT.

In SQL, I've had no trouble doing this like so...

```
SELECT
item.noun,
comp.type
FROM
DBO.W_ITEM item
INNER JOIN DBO.W_COMPONENT comp ON item.id = comp.id
```

However, I can't get this to work in HQL.

I've tried it like this...

```
SELECT
item.noun,
comp.type
FROM
InventoryItemInv item
INNER JOIN item.components comp ON item.id = comp.id
```

but the HQL doesn't seem to know what to do with the ON - and says it's an unexpected token.  According to all the literature, HQL supports the ON keyword.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the ON clause to define the binding column, Hibernate will infer it from the relationship defined in the model, following HQL query should work for you

```
SELECT item.noun, comp.type
FROM InventoryItemInv item
INNER JOIN item.components comp
```